# Jenkins scanning multibranch pipeline fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I restarted the jenkins server and after restart, we don't see the branches (scanning multibranch pipeline fails).

I get below error message:

```
ERROR: [Wed Oct 06 12:08:48 UTC 2021] Could not fetch branches from source 6da85d5a-5f43-42bd-b356-24d124cc19f3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JENKINS-42511: attempted to redundantly create release%2F6.0.0.10 in org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject@a851a87[FXZ_Automation/fips_mssql_cartridge_automation_pipeline]
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$SCMHeadObserverImpl.observeNew(MultiBranchProject.java:2056)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$SCMHeadObserverImpl.observe(MultiBranchProject.java:1991)
    at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMSourceRequest.process(SCMSourceRequest.java:357)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieveBranches(BitbucketSCMSource.java:746)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieve(BitbucketSCMSource.java:588)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:373)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:283)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:641)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1032)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
[Wed Oct 06 12:08:48 UTC 2021] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.99 sec
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of FXZ_Automation » fips_mssql_cartridge_automation_pipeline
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JENKINS-42511: attempted to redundantly create release%2F6.0.0.10 in org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject@a851a87[FXZ_Automation/fips_mssql_cartridge_automation_pipeline]
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$SCMHeadObserverImpl.observeNew(MultiBranchProject.java:2056)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$SCMHeadObserverImpl.observe(MultiBranchProject.java:1991)
    at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMSourceRequest.process(SCMSourceRequest.java:357)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieveBranches(BitbucketSCMSource.java:746)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieve(BitbucketSCMSource.java:588)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:373)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:283)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:641)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1032)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

How do I restore the branches? Could someone please guide me?

Comment: "attempted to redundantly create release%2F6.0.0.10". %2F looks like Jenkins has issues encoding the project/release name, maybe because of the delimiter "-".
Potentially related issue:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-30744?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

Comment: Thanks @nulldroid. In which file should I add this code? - https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-30744?focusedCommentId=244977&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-244977

Comment: You can add code to Jenkinsfile. Could you show the part of your Jenkinsfile, where it is fetching branches? It seems you are using Bitbucket plugin. are you using the latest version 1.1.29? Also, which version of Jenkins? Are you using webhooks or the old HTTP posts from Bitbucket?

Comment: Bitbucket uses default branch names like "release/". The "/" in branch name is the problem I believe. Make sure you got the latest branch-api-plugin installed. This should escape paths properly.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/releases/tag/branch-api-2.7.0

Comment: I have branch-api v2.5.5, bitbucket v1.1.29, Jenkins v2.228

Comment: Latest branch-api plugin is 2.7.0. This Jenkins setting could fix it:

-Djenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX